# Get 1 more post in loop

Tags: loop

In a simple loop, for example:

```
$loop = new wp_query(array('posts_per_page' => 3));

while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'skip_me', true) == true){
        // do something to ask for one more post, 
        // as we really want 3 total!
        continue;
    } else {
        the_content();
    }
endwhile;
```

If a certain condition is met, we might pass over a post, but what if we still *really* want to get exactly 3 posts? Rather than arbitrarily asking for extra posts and then stopping after 3 successes - is there any other way to ask of the loop, to get one more post?

I suppose with this exact example the easiest thing would be to do a `meta_query` within the arguments. But what if it weren't that easy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably [add a meta query to your `WP_Query()` args](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters):

```
$loop = new wp_query(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        // Meta Query
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'skip_me',
                'value' => 'true',
                'compare' => '!='
            )
        )
    ) 
);
```

Or you could perhaps go with the simpler version in this case:

```
$loop = new wp_query(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        // Meta Query
        'meta_key' => 'skip_me',
        'meta_value' => 'true',
        'meta_compare' => '!='
    ) 
);
```

In both cases, posts that have the meta value "true" for "skip_me" will not be included in the queried object.

Comment: While I am curious how to do this without a meta_query, I don't currently have an example of a use-case where something besides post_meta is used to filter the posts, so this is technically correct ;)

Answer (score 1):

> While I am curious how to do this without a meta_query...

You can't "ask" the query to grab another post, you just have to run another query, but that would quickly become convoluted, not to mention labor intensive for the server. Something like this (untested):

```
$loop = new wp_query(array('posts_per_page' => 3));
$grab_more = false;
while($loop->have_posts()) { 
    $loop->the_post();
    if ($grab_more) {
        $more = new wp_query(array('posts_per_page' => 1,'offset' => 3));
        if(!empty($more->posts[0])) {
            setup_postdata($more->posts[0]);
        }
        $grab_more = false;
    }
    if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'skip_me', true) == true){
        // do something to ask for one more post, 
        // as we really want 3 total!
        echo 'get more';
        $grab_more = true;
        continue;
    } else {
        echo 'the_content';
        the_content();
    }
}
```

I am *sure* that that is buggy. I made that up in about a minute and ***I am sure*** that it does not work correctly in all cases-- maybe it doesn't work correctly in any cases :). It is just a bit of conceptualization. I can't easily test it, but that ***is not the right way to do this anyway***. You could generate a huge number of database queries with that, for one, and the looping could really slow things down. The way to do it is:

1. With query arguments if possible. This what @ChipBennet suggested and in your sample case this is the correct answer hands down.
2. With filters if there are no query arguments. If you are good enough
   with `SQL` you can make the query do anything you want with [the
   right set of filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Filters). If you can't use the provided query arguments this is the only right option as far as I am concerned. Trying to nest queries like this is convoluted and just wrong.

Comment: I think this is a good approach. @Rarst also had an idea whereby a non-meta edit-side approach might, for example, add post IDs to a field in wp_options, so that `post__not_in` could be used to exclude posts referenced in that field. Also complicated, but easy on the database.